# How to run a .exe from a linux terminal (cloud9)

Tags: c#, linux, terminal, cloud9-ide

I've been using the hosted version of Cloud9 for a while now, and I've compiled a .exe file from C#. how would I go about running this? `sudo ./calc.exe` messes up the character encoding of the terminal, and that's all. I have also tried running it from the built in "run" utility, but it says that "command calc.exe not found" How do I run this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install mono. (Check, maybe it's already installed `mono --version`)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Then you can run your .NET applications like so: `mono calc.exe`

[More info](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/)